# I am unable to use \underbrace in elsarticle template

Tags: underbrace

In the elsarticle template, I am not able to use the command \underbrace, whereas, in a simple latex file, the command is working fine. Following is the code:

```
\documentclass[review,12pt,3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E_i=\underbrace{\left(H_1+H_2 S_h +H_3 \left(\frac{T-T_0}{T_0}\right)\right)}_{\text{H}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I have attached a picture of this also.
[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal example of code reproducing the issue, not a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad interaction between `txfonts` (that's loaded with the `times` option to `elsarticle`) and `esint`. Indeed, we see

```
\documentclass[review,12pt,3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}_{\text{text}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Don't use `times`, but load NewTX.

```
\documentclass[review,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}_{\text{text}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked.